# boolean not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list' .. despite having a clean array?

Tags: python, arrays, list, int, typeerror

I have an array of size 10000, which contains random integers in it between 1-200 made using the following code:

```
x = np.random.randint(1,201, size=10000)
```

Next, I'm taking a random sample of 100, from this array and finding its mean value and putting it in an array called meen:

```
meen = []
for z in range(0, 50000):    
    randomSample=random.sample(list(x), 100 )
    meanOfSample=np.mean(randomSample)  
    meen.append(meanOfSample)
```

I assume the past two codes work correctly because when I print(meen) I get an array:

`[102.89, 106.14, 104.73, 97.78, 101.94, 98.94, 97.43, 98.92, 101.84, 99.64......]` fifty thousand long.

Now, the issue is when I am trying to find the number of values that fall within a range. For example, If I say I want to find the amount of numbers in meen that fall between 95 and 100 I tried the code:

```
((95 <= meen) & (meen <= 100)).sum()
```

But I get the error: "TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'list'"

I've seen various similar problems with this error on this website, but they all involved having bad arrays. I think my array is fine..? It only has numbers, no strings, or anything else that should cause issues.

Comment: `meen` is **not an array**. It is a `list`. You are mixing up python `list` objects with `numpy.ndarray` objects. Don't do that. Work with one of those. Or perhaps sometimes it makes sense to use an auxiliary list to accumulate values one-by-one, but then convert to an array *if you want to use it like an array*

Comment: For example, why on earth would you do: `random.sample(list(x), 100 )`??? you can just do `np.random.choice(x, 100, replace=False)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`meen` is a list, not a numpy array. Try adding this after your loop:

```
meen = np.asarray(meen)
```

Comment: or just `np.array(meen)`

Comment: np.asarray is nice because it's a nop if the input is already an array. In this case it doesn't help, but in general coding, it's often good to use asarray for time and memory efficiency.

Comment: I would say it depends, generally, you should *know* what you inputs are, and even if you are using an array, you may want to create a new one. In any case, this is still a fine solution and I upvoted

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga If you're writing library code, then it's good practice in Python to be tolerant of user inputs and "just do the right thing." For example, most numpy functions effectively call np.asarray on their inputs so that you can pass in lists, tuples, or anything array-like. As you said though, if you know you want a new array (e.g. you're about to modify the array and don't want to change the caller's data), then definitely calling np.array is the best solution.